# how to obtain NSURL from currentDirectoryPath

Tags: ios, nsurl

```
  NSURL *currentURL = [[NSURL alloc] 
    initWithString: [fileManager currentDirectoryPath]];
```

This call returns nil. How should I change it so that it returns a pointer to the NSURL for the current working directory?

Comment: What do you mean with "working directory"?

Comment: I mean "working directory" as used in the Apple documentation, including, for instance, the NSFileManager Class Reference.

Comment: Answer: Change initWithString: to initFileURLWithPath:.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change initWithString: to initFileURLWithPath:.

Answer (score 0):

- Documents directory: `NSDocumentDirectory`
- Cache directory: `NSCachesDirectory`
- Resource-specific directory: `[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource%3aofType%3a))

Comment: None of these will give me the NSURL for the current working directory, unless by coincidence the current working directory is Documents or Caches.

Comment: There's no such thing as a working directory on iOS. You're either using files from your app bundle or using files that you store in the cache or document directories. No other file usage is allowed on iOS.

Comment: Based on my experience and reading of the NSFileManager Class Reference and File System Programming Guide, I don't believe this is correct. You can make subdirectories in Documents, Library, or tmp, and you can make any of them the current working directory.

Comment: True, but as far as I know iOS doesn't actually use this. You can set the working directory by using `changeCurrentDirectoryPath` but it is strongly recommended to avoid this and work with `NSDocumentDirectory` and other directories instead, since a core concept of iOS is that the user does not have to worry about files and folders.

Comment: I would be grateful if you would point me to the Apple documentation in which it is "strongly recommended" that one not use changeCurrentDirectoryPath in iOS apps. I don't believe that it does. In any event, I still need an answer to my original question.

Comment: I gave you the answer... By setting it manually (4th comment)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
 NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    int ind=0;
    NSString* destinationFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/input%d.mp3", documentsDirectory,ind];
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the path to Documents or a file in Documents; I'm looking for the NSURL for the current working directory.